# How to send image for processing (Object Detection) to firebase Ml-kit and retrieve output?

Tags: android, android-studio, object-detection, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to work on the application provided by firebase for ML-kit android development, GitHub link https://github.com/firebase/mlkit-material-android In this project they said that you have to modify the SearchEngine class implementation but I'm not able to identify what all things I have to change and how the code will look like.

Answer (score 0):

Here are something you can do:

1. In the ML Kit sample app's SearchEngine class, you can get the imageBytes of the detected object: https://github.com/firebase/mlkit-material-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/ml/md/java/productsearch/SearchEngine.java#L66
2. Then you can send that image to your own product search backend. One way to build such a backend is using https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs You will be able to find more details in the Product-Search API documentation and tutorials. There is also a google group for that https://groups.google.com/g/cloud-vision-discuss, where you can ask Product-Search related questions and find answers.